# What can I share with an interview candidate (whom I referred)?

Tags: interviewing

If I refer a friend/colleague for a job opening, how much can I share with them beyond what's in the public job description?

Obviously, no trade secrets or IP. What about the job "family" information from the intranet for that position? Details on team size/structure? Organizational history? More detailed information on the technical stack?

As a candidate, I would ask questions about all of these things. Even trying to find out before the interview. But, I'm trying to help my friend be more competitive.

Answer (score 6):

I think sharing team size and technical stack would be fine. If I recommend someone for a position, I already believe that the person has the various skills to be a good addition to the team, so I'd want that person to successfully complete the interview. Sharing the technical stack with that person gives them a chance to prepare for the interview.

Things like the structure or the culture / history may make it easy for him/her to decide if it's an attractive position in the first place (just because I like it, my friend may not).

In the past, I even mentioned some of the interview questions that I was asked during my interview. I wasn't present at my friend's interview and when (prior to the interview) I was asked if I gave these details to my friend, I answered yes. This way my friend had a chance to get ready for the interview but the company still get an honest interview at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Stick to the details that will help your friend make a better decision about working with your company.

Sharing secrets about the interview process will undermine your team's ability to make a good decision, will set the expectation with your friend that your company is a place where you back channel for promotions, and may put your friend in a position where they will have performance issues and unfair expectations imposed upon them.

Sell them on the company, then hand them off to others.